# Unable to Create New Contact Field

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, import

I'm currently setting up the CIVICRM platform, now at the stage of importing data I am  unable to create new contact fields, I followed the instructions available to create custom fields however none of the created custom fields is visible when mapping the data for import.

Please assist as soon as possible.

Edit: here are some screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

@fuzion, I yes the fields are set to searchable, on contact report I can also see the created custom field, but not in the import page.

@Aidan, Please expand more I do not completely understand you.

Comment: Hi. Welcome Funbi. Did you set your Fields to be searchable? if not, try changing one or two and see if they then become visible in the import mapping.

Comment: If you create a contact normally via the UI do the custom fields show there?

Comment: fuzion, I yes the fields are set to searchable, on contact report I can also see the created custom field, but not in the import page. @Aidan, Please expand more I do not completely understand you. I have added some screenshots please find. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AYV8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AYV8.png) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pcS0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pcS0.png) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94ZOe.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94ZOe.png) [![enter image description here](ht

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the custom field has been set up to allow Multiple Records, and you did not click on the ? to read the notes about this type of setting - and those notes would have explained that the 'special power' of multiple records impacts on the ability or approach to other functionality including Importing records.